# C++ list functions not worling

Tags: c++, struct, pass-by-reference, singly-linked-list, pass-by-value

I'm tryin to create a program that let me add elements in tail of a list and then prints them. It doesn't give me an error but he doesn't do anything. What am I doing wrong ?

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
 
struct lista{
    int val;
    lista *next;
};

typedef lista* ptr_lista;

void tail_add(ptr_lista head, int valore){
    if(head=NULL){
         head=new lista;
         head->val=valore;
         head->next=NULL;
    } else {
        ptr_lista p=head;
        while(p->next!=NULL){
                p=p->next;
        }
        p->next=new lista;
        p->next->val=valore;
        p->next->next=NULL;
    }
}

void print(ptr_lista p){
     while(p!=NULL){
            cout<<p->val<< " ";
            p=p->next;
      }
}

int main(){
    ptr_lista m;
    tail_add(m,5);
    tail_add(m,6);
    print(m);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters the pointer `m` is not initialized and has an indeterminate value

```
ptr_lista m;
```

You need to initialize it

```
ptr_lista m = nullptr;
```

The function accepts the pointer by value

```
void tail_add(ptr_lista head, int valore){
```

So changing the parameter `head` within the function like

```
 head=new lista;
```

has no effect on the original pointer `m` declared in main.

You need to declare the parameter as a reference to the pointer

```
void tail_add(ptr_lista &head, int valore){
```

The function can be defined the following way

```
void tail_add( ptr_lista &head, int valore )
{
    ptr_lista new_lista_ptr = new lista { valore, nullptr };

    if ( head == nullptr )
    {
         head = new_lista_ptr;
    } 
    else 
    {
        ptr_lista p = head;

        while ( p->next ) p = p->next;

        p->next = new_lista_ptr;
    }
}
```

Pay attention to that it is not a good idea to introduce an alias for a pointer like

```
typedef lista* ptr_lista;
```

For example if you will write

```
const ptr_lista
```

then it means

```
lista * const
```

not

```
const lista *
```

that is required for the declaration of the parameter of the function `print` because it does not change nodes of the list.